# Can not find a [RegularExpression] inside my asp.net mvc to allow max of 2 digits

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application and i have a decimal field with the following data type inside sql server `Decimal(19,2)`. now i want to do a check that the user can only enter 2 digits, but they can add number such as 10 , 20 (without any digits).. but if they set digits to check that there are max of two digits.

now i try the following RegularExpression but none of them worked well:-

This RegularExpression will not allow users to enter numbers that do not contain digits:-

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Value can't have more than 2 decimal places")]
public Nullable<decimal> CostPrice { get; set; }
```

and this RegularExpression,, will raise an error if the user try to enter digits:-

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(\d{0,2})$", ErrorMessage = "error Message")]
public Nullable<decimal> CostPrice { get; set; }
```

so can anyone adivce what is the best RegularExpression, that force users to enter max of 2 digits , while allow them to enter numbers without any digits?

Comment: By digits do you mean decimal places?

Comment: @DoNothing yes exactly decimal places

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```
^(?!\s*[0-9]{0,2}\s*$).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- validates that the string is at most 2 digits surrounded by white space
- If the string contains upto 2 digits then the expression will be false
- if the string contains more than 2 digits then the express will be true
- if the string contains any letters, then the expression will be true

**Live Example**

https://regex101.com/r/vQ1gW1/1

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{0,2}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 0
                             and 2 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: but your example <<^(?!\s*[0-9]{0,2}\s*$).*$>> is not related to my question what i am searching for is to accept at most 2 decimals ,, so these should be valid in my case 10 OR 10.1 OR 1.23 .. but these should not be valid 10.123 OR 11.2345 .. did u get my point ?